# how to display a single item if no delimeter is used in sql

Tags: sql

```
 Select FirstName, LastName, Product  reverse(
       replace(STUFF(reverse(Product),
       charindex(',',reverse(Product)),0,'#'),'#,',' dna ')
       ) as PrimaryProduct
FROM myStuff;
```

`myStuff` is the main query.

Above query only works if there is a ',' present. How to make it work for no delimiters, i.e. for a single item or a product which has space between two words and which does not require to append the "and" string in the result

Please help!

Comment: Which type of database do you use?

Comment: It is a Realtime Database

Comment: I tried with the below query but am receiving an error like "Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint."                                                       Select FirstName, LastName, Case Product When charindex(',',reverse(Product)) then   reverse(
    replace(STUFF(reverse(Product),
       charindex(',',reverse(Product)),0,'#'),'#,',' dna ')
       ) 
       else
       Product 
       end
FROM myStuff;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I need to clarify two questions.

1. When we want to add and between last two words, we must be able to identify the two words separately. Ex: "Good morning". It is not possible to identify good and morning as separate words. So, when we need to any delimiter It must be capable to differentiate the words.

2.To get the exact answer when there is only one word. Use CASE as follows.

```
 Select FirstName, LastName, Product,  
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', Product) > 0 THEN  
      reverse(
               replace(STUFF(reverse(Product),
               charindex(',',reverse(Product)),0,'#'),'#,',' dna ')
            ) 
    ELSE 
      Product
    END as PrimaryProduct
    FROM myStuff;
```